# How to put delay before doing an operation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher, thread-sleep

I tried to use the below code to make a 2 second delay before navigating to the next window. But the thread is invoking first and the textblock gets displayed for a microsecond and landed into the next page. I heard a dispatcher would do that.

Here is my snippet:

```
tbkLabel.Text = "two mins delay";
Thread.Sleep(2000);
Page2 _page2 = new Page2();
_page2.Show();
```

Answer (score 117, accepted):

The call to Thread.Sleep is blocking the UI thread.  You need to wait asynchronously.

Method 1: use a DispatcherTimer

```
tbkLabel.Text = "two seconds delay";

var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2) };
timer.Start();
timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
    {
        timer.Stop();
        var page = new Page2();
        page.Show();
    };
```

Method 2: use Task.Delay

```
tbkLabel.Text = "two seconds delay";

Task.Delay(2000).ContinueWith(_ => 
   { 
     var page = new Page2();
     page.Show();
   }
);
```

Method 3: The .NET 4.5 way, use async/await

```
// we need to add the async keyword to the method signature
public async void TheEnclosingMethod()
{
    tbkLabel.Text = "two seconds delay";

    await Task.Delay(2000);
    var page = new Page2();
    page.Show();
}
```

Comment: Method 1 might show the new page multiple times in case the timer ticks multiple times and the app is too slow handling the first one.

Comment: @usr Actually it won't.  Internally the timer is a single shot and is restarted after raising the Tick event.

Comment: @usr, well I didn't know.  I took a peek with Resharper :)

Comment: @Phil Method 1 works fine.. but in method 2 the task does not have the delay property in wpf it seems. BTW i'm using framework3 and vs 2010..

Comment: Also I have found this does the same: tbkLabel.Text = "two mins de  lay";
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => Thread.Sleep(2000)),DispatcherPriority.Background);
            Page2 _page2 = new Page2();
            _page2.Show();

Comment: Just for the record, `Task.Delay()` is unfortunately also a .NET 4.5 method.

Comment: How would you modify the first method to add a countdown timer that displays seconds left to page switch?

Comment: @lahjaton_j either backgroundworker, or async workflow waiting, sending notifications / triggering events, and counting down ...

Comment: Wouldn't you need to dispatch `page.show()` in Method 2?

Answer (score 0):

Method 4: .NET 5.0+

```
    Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { Task.Delay(2000) });
```

This solution has no downsides. It can be used in loops which is for "DispatcherTimer" and "ContinueWith" impossible.