# WPF Update grid visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

After some search on web I have set up this simple example:

PropertyChangedBase.cs

```
public class PropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        //Raise the PropertyChanged event on the UI Thread, with the relevant propertyName parameter:
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }));
    }
 }
```

UserViewModel.cs

```
public class UserViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private Visibility _showUserWindow = Visibility.Collapsed;
    public Visibility ShowUserWindow {
        get { return _showUserWindow; }
        set {
            _showUserWindow = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ShowUserWindow"); //This is important!!!
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid Margin="43,28,247,129" Background="AliceBlue" Visibility="{Binding ShowUserWindow}"/>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="349,150,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    UserViewModel userViewModel;

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();

        userViewModel = new UserViewModel();
        DataContext = userViewModel;
    }

    private void Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        userViewModel.ShowUserWindow = Visibility.Visible;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        userViewModel.ShowUserWindow = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Right now grid becomes collapsed after 1 sec, I would like to update UI before timer starts. What I am doing wrong?

**Edit:**
Thread.Sleep line immitates some work, that takes some time to complete.
Grid should become visible before work starts and show some info about that work and become collapsed after work is done.

Comment: Why do you have the Thread.Sleep line?

Comment: what are we  trying to do here ?

Comment: If you want to delay `userViewModel.ShowUserWindow = Visibility.Collapsed;` for 1 second, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599884/how-to-put-delay-before-doing-an-operation-in-wpf

Comment: replace Thead.Sleep by Task.Delay ...

Comment: So what you have / want is more of a "Progress" display of ... Hey... I'm working here... give me a minute to get things setup... then disappear?

Comment: @DRapp: Yes. Exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you should consider doing the **Thread.Sleep(1000)** operation on a separate thread, not on the UI thread. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363377/how-do-i-run-a-simple-bit-of-code-in-a-new-thread) for that.
Other than that, try to use `yourGrid.UpdateLayout()` method after setting its `visibility` to `collapsed`.

LE:
Most probably, his `Thread.Sleep(1000)` stands for something like a database operation, for example, something that takes time.

LE2: A `BackgroundWorker` will do the trick. Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363377/how-do-i-run-a-simple-bit-of-code-in-a-new-thread)!

Comment: I'm thinking the BackgroundWorker helped you (right?), just to make it clear for the future visitors. Good luck !;)

Comment: `UpdateLayout()` will not help. I don't know the exact reason of it, but I think that any UI redraw operations is send to Dispatcher queue, and the queue will not continue until the current code in UI thread is finished (and it obviously will not finish until `Thread.Sleep` is finished).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET 4.5, you can use Task.Delay() to allow UI to update itself before starting the actual work:

```
private async void Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    userViewModel.ShowUserWindow = Visibility.Visible;
    await Task.Delay(1);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    userViewModel.ShowUserWindow = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Please note that `await Task.Delay(1);` should be used even after you replace `Thread.Sleep(1000)` with actual work.

However this should be used only if your work can be done only in UI thread and cannot be moved to a background thread (for example, massive loading of UI elements). Otherwise the correct approach is to move the work to a background thread:

```
private async void Button_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    userViewModel.ShowUserWindow = Visibility.Visible;
    await Task.Start(() => {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    };
    userViewModel.ShowUserWindow = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```